# Update field on nested array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

i have a model of how this:

```
_id:ObjectId("5705005b240166e927f841cb")
figures: [
  {
    id: "5433234"
    figure: [
     {
      "id":"figure_543",
      "active": false,
      "name": "Alvar"
     },
     {
      "id":"figure_431",
      "active": false,
      "name": "Peter"
     }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "1276544"
    figure: [
     {
      "id":"figure_123",
      "active": false,
      "name": "Jhon"
     }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "1231645"
    figure: [
     {
      "id":"figure_154",
      "active": false,
      "name": "Luka"
     }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'am doing this:

```
db.collection.update({"_id": userId, "figures.figure.id": figureId}, {$set:{"figures.figure.$.active": true}})
```

***userId*** and ***figureId*** are variables that come from req.body on expressjs.

But i see this:

> The positional $ operator cannot be used for queries which traverse more than one array, such as queries that traverse arrays nested within other arrays, because the replacement for the $ placeholder is a single value

My question is, **how can i update the field *active* of *figure* on nested array with mongoose?**

Thank's!!!